# Help with a SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have to perform a SQL query to get the top 10 albums according to number of views. The number of views is actually the sum of the views for each song in the specified album.

My tables are:

```
albums:
- album_id
- album_name
- album_owner

songs:
- song_id
- song_name
- song_album
- song_owner
- song_views
```

Can you guys help me out with this one?

Comment: Do you need to do it in only one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select sum(song_views) as 'song_sum',album_name 
from albums a 
inner join 
songs s 
on a.album_id = s.song_album 
group by album_name 
order by song_sum DESC 
limit 0,10;
```

if song_album refers to album id...

Comment: I think this is it! 
The result looks ok.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT  TOP 10 a.album_id, a.album_name, a.album_owner, SUM(s.song_views)
FROM    albums a
        INNER JOIN
                songs s
                ON a.album_id = s.song_album
GROUP BY a.album_id, a.album_name, a.album_owner
ORDER BY SUM(s.song_views) DESC
```

Comment: Nice - excuse my ignorance but is the TOP clause just MSSQL specific? What would be equivalents in PostgreSQL/SQLite/MySQL?

Comment: @ meder use limit 10 ... for top 10

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's Transact-SQL rather than ANSI, so should work in SQL Server and Sybase for starters. Look for other means of limiting in your own DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
select top 10 song_album
from songs
group by song_album
order by sum(song_views) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not run this, but it should be along the lines of

```
select album_name, sum(song_views) as views from albums join songs on songs.album_id = songs.song_album group by album_id order by views desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT TOP 10 song_album FROM songs
>   GROUP BY song_album ORDER BY
>   sum(song_views) desc